# In case of a given graph , Is that possible to build trapezoidal map in linear time

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

[This regarding to Computational geometry in CS]

Let's say that I have a graph G which contains v vectices and e edges, For instance a veronoi diagram VD(G).

```
[I'd like to build a trapezodial map out of my given graph,][1]
```

Is that possible to build trapezodial map in linear time for a given graph, Instead of O(nlogn) regular construction time ?

I have been thinking about sweep line trapezoidal map construction where for each edge during the sweep line would construct the upper and lower sites.

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the graph may consist of v/2 horizontal segments stacked on top of each other. Building the trapezoidal map means you sort these segments by height, and that takes at least c v log v time.